# Find range of possible values for probability of intersection given individual probabilities

Tags: probability

If given probability of $A$ is $a$ and probability of $B$ is $b$, how do I find min/max probability of intersection? Max value of intersection would be $\min(a,b)$, how do I find the min?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if $a+b \le 1$, then presumably one can find disjoint sets $A$ and $B$ with ${\rm P}A = a$ and
${\rm P}B = b$. so in this case, the min is 0.

if $a+b > 1$, we get a smallest intersection by choosing $B$ to contain all of $A^C$, which has probability $1-a$ and then adding to that a piece of $A$ to bring ${\rm P}B$ up to $b$. so the piece of $A$ added in has to have probability $b - (1-a) = a+b - 1$. this last quantity is then the min probability for the intersection when $a+b > 1$.

so in any case. the min is $(a+b-1)^+$.

Comment: your last explanation on finding the smallest intersection can be applied to all cases. Min `A∩B` is `max(a+b-1,0)`

Answer (score 1):

The min is the smaller of two values: $\min(a,b) = a$ if $a < b$ and $b$ otherwise. Though I do not think this is what you are asking for...

Comment: what? the question says 'blah blah blah would be $min(a,b)$, how do I find the min?' I answered the question.

Comment: @shabbychef I agree; bad questions should be punished with no answers.

Comment: No, that's not what he's asking for. He asked for the min of the intersection, as can be deducted by careful reading of the first of the two sentences in the opening post.

Comment: @mbq - whats wrong with the question?

Comment: @saminny You could have formulated it better so that it would be less ambiguous and easier to understand. shabbychef just pointed it out with his answer.

Comment: before the question was edited to have proper LaTeX, when I answered it, it was very hard to parse. Look at this in plaintext: 'Max value of intersection would be min(a,b). how do I find the min?' 
With the proper markup, it is much easier to parse. (Though it looks like a homework question to me...)

Comment: If $a$ and $b$ are sufficiently small, $\min$ could be $0$. E.g. consider a population consisting of 50% cats and 50% dogs. Let $A=\text{animal is a dog}$, $B=\text{animal can retract nails}$. Clearly, $P(A)=P(B)=0.5$ but $P(A\cap B)=0$.